# Adding text to each column of MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a database table in MYSQL with around 1000 rows. In the table I have a column called 'overview'. In each row, this column has some value and at the end of that value I have a specific line (text) starting with: 'Source...'

Now what I want is, I want to remove this line from each column and replace it with some other text content.

I believe it can be accomplished with some smart query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) in your query like this

```
    UPDATE your_table SET col_name = REPLACE(col_name , ‘Source...’, ‘new_val’)
    WHERE col_name LIKE '%Source...';
```

Check Out the **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c178d/3)**.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database has a handy and simple string function `REPLACE()` that allows table data with the matching string (`from_string`) to be replaced by new string (`to_string`).

The syntax of [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is:

```
REPLACE (text_string, from_string, to_string)
```

In your case, you can do this way:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `column` = REPLACE(column , 'Source...', 'Replaced Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace`

update TBL 
   set overview = Replace(picture, 'Source..', 'replacement')

keep a backup of the table before anything.Or you can do it on a copy.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following:

```
update table_name set col_name = replace(column_name , ‘Source...’, ‘Replaced String...’);
```